# AppDomain.DoCallBack requires ReflectionPermission?

Tags: c#, .net, remoting, appdomain, isolation

I have this class, instance of which I create in an AppDomain with no permissions but [SecurityPermissionFlag.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securitypermissionflag.aspx):

```
class IsolationEntryPoint : MarshalByRefObject
{
    // main is the original AppDomain with all the permissions
    public void Enter(AppDomain main)
    {
        // these work correctly
        Console.WriteLine("Currently in: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Host: " + main.FriendlyName);

        // the exception is thrown here
        main.DoCallBack(this.MyCallBack);
    }

    public void MyCallBack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Currently in: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
}
```

The odd thing is that I get SecurityException in the DoCallback line saying:

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

MSDNsays [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about permission requirements of AppDomain.DoCallBack:

> ReflectionPermission when invoked late-bound through mechanisms such
>   as Type.InvokeMember.

**The call is not using anything like [Type.InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), why am I getting the exception?**

**EDIT**:

For clarity, here is the code I use to create the AppDomain with the isolation object:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var setup = new AppDomainSetup();
        setup.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

        var evidence = new Evidence();

        var permissions = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        permissions.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

        var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            "isolationDomain",
            evidence,
            setup,
            permissions);

        var handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(
            domain, typeof(IsolationEntryPoint).Assembly.ManifestModule.FullyQualifiedName,
            typeof(IsolationEntryPoint).FullName);

        var instance = (IsolationEntryPoint)handle.Unwrap();

        instance.Enter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }
```

These two pieces code are my full application, there is nothing else (so the exception should be easy to reproduce).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple: You missed to add the *public* access modifier to `class IsolationEntryPoint`, i.e after changing the class signature like so your sample runs just fine:

```
public class IsolationEntryPoint : MarshalByRefObject
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Oh course. ReShaper is even yelling at me to give the class an access qualifier. Thanks for help, +100 for you (once SO allows me to) :)

Comment: Yo, sometimes _use the tools_ trumps _use the source_ even ;) - Thanks for the generous bounty, which makes solving those puzzles all the more worthwhile :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below and it seems to work.

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SecurityPermission t = new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution);
        t.Demand();
        IsolationEntryPoint x = new IsolationEntryPoint();
        x.Enter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
    }
}


class IsolationEntryPoint : MarshalByRefObject
{
    // main is the original AppDomain with all the permissions 
    public void Enter(AppDomain main)
    {
        // these work correctly 
        Console.WriteLine("Currently in: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
        Console.WriteLine("Host: " + main.FriendlyName);

        // the exception is thrown here 
        main.DoCallBack(this.MyCallBack);
    }

    public void MyCallBack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Currently in: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you are executing it from the default AppDomain which does have the Reflection privilege by default. I'm executing it from AppDomain no permissions but Execute.

Comment: You can try adding custom permissions to the AppDomain explicitly by                                   appDomainObject.PermissionSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

Comment: How would that help? The AppDomain has the execute privilege alright (and I for purposes of security, I don't want to add the reflection privlege). I also posted full code I use to create the AppDomain.